# Go: Property of an interface is undefined despite existing in the documentation

Tags: go

I am writing a program that iterates through an AST (abstract syntax tree). When I execute the following piece of code:

```
val := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(currStatement))
for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
    varName := val.Type().Field(i).Name
    varType := val.Type().Field(i).Type
    varValue := val.Field(i).Interface()

    if (varName == "Body") {
        fmt.Printf("%v %v %v\n", varName,varType,varValue)
    }
}
fmt.Println()
```

I get the following output:

```
Body *ast.BlockStmt &{2795 [0xc0001044c0] 2867}
```

Which indicates that `val.Field(i).Interface()` is the type `*ast.BlockStmt`. However, according to the documentation here (https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#BlockStmt):
[image]

It is clear that `BlockStmt` has the property `List`. However, when I run the following line of code in the `for` loop to extract the value of the property `List` (which I will eventually iterate through):

```
fmt.Printf("%v %v %v\n", varName,varType,varValue.List)
```

I get the following error:

```
varValue.List undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
```

Comment: Note that the go/ast package has functions for iterating through the AST:  [ast.Inspect](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#Inspect) and [ast.Walk](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#Walk).  You may have good reason to write your function, but I wanted to call those out in case you missed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`varValue` is of type `interface{}` that points to a `BlockStmt` instance. You have to use type-assertion to get the `BlockStmt` from it:

```
blk:=varValue.(*ast.BlockStmt)
```

Then you can access `blk.List`.